# How to create Spring Integration Flow from two MessageProducerSpec?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration, Java DSL (release 1.1.3)
I have my `org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow` defined as follows

```
 return IntegrationFlows.from(messageProducerSpec) 
            .handle(handler) 
            .handle(aggregator) 
            .handle(endpoint) 
            .get();
    }
```

`messageProducerSpec` is instance  of `org.springframework.integration.dsl.amqp.AmqpBaseInboundChannelAdapterSpec`

I would like my integration flow to consume messages from TWO separate `messageProducerSpecs` (two separate `SimpleMessageListenerContainers`, each using diffrent `ConnectionFactory`). How is it possible to construct integrationFlow from more than one messageProducerSpec? I see no integration component that is able to consume messages from multiple sources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no reason to do that in Spring Integration.

You always can output different endpoints to the same `MessageChannel`.

Therefore you should have several simple `IntegrationFlow`s for all those `messageProducerSpec` and finish them with the same channel, where also should be the main flow which will listen from that channel:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow producer1() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from(messageProducerSpec1) 
        .channel("input") 
        .get();
} 

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow producer2() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from(messageProducerSpec2) 
        .channel("input") 
        .get();
} 

...

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from("input") 
        .handle(handler) 
        .handle(aggregator) 
        .handle(endpoint) 
        .get();
}
```