# How to create a spring integration flow with many producers

Tags: spring-integration

I read this [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577608/how-to-crate-spring-integration-flow-from-two-messageproducerspec) question, and I have a complementary question.

I have a spring integration flow that works like this today :

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow udpSource1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(new MulticastReceivingChannelAdapter("224.0.0.1", 2000)).
            transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer("utf8")).channel("stringified").get();

}
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow udpSource2() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(new MulticastReceivingChannelAdapter("224.0.0.1", 2001)).
            transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer("utf8")).channel("stringified").get();

}
```

And I have severals (10) UDP sources.

I would like to create one flow with all my UDP sources, all of them pushing data into the "stringified" channel.

I would like to get all my UDP port from a ArrayList, then iterate over this list and create the UDP sources...

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called `IntegrationFlowRegistration`: https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available.

Look into [Dynamic TCP Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client) for similar solution.

The key code is like this:

```
private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
        String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
        Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");
        Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
        String hostPort = host + port;

        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        handler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(handler);
        IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
                this.flowContext.registration(flow)
                        .addBean(cf)
                        .id(hostPort + ".flow")
                        .register();
        MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();
        this.subFlows.put(hostPort, inputChannel);
        return inputChannel;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I use the tips given by Artem to solve my problem.

```
@Configuration
public class UdpSources {
    @Value("#{'${udp.nmea.listeningports}'.split(',')}")
    List<Integer> allUDPPorts;

    public static final String outChannel = "stringified";

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createAllUDPEndPoints(){
        for(int port : allUDPPorts){
            flowContext.registration(getUdpChannel(port)).autoStartup(false).id("udpSource"+port).register();
        }
    }

    private IntegrationFlow getUdpChannel(int port){
        return IntegrationFlows.from(new MulticastReceivingChannelAdapter("224.0.0.1", port)).
                transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer("UTF-8")).channel(outChannel).get();
    }
}
```