# Spring integration flow with two sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-annotations

I try to create a flow which get message from 2 sources (1 mqtt and one from a user service interaction) and it generate message to another mqtt. 
In fact, i try to use this answer: [How to crate Spring Integration Flow from two MessageProducerSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577608/how-to-crate-spring-integration-flow-from-two-messageproducerspec)

And here is my result:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
            .channel("mainMessageChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttTestMessageFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(messageService.testInbound())
            .channel("mainMessageChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainMessageFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("mainMessageChannel")
            .handle(eventServiceHandler())
            .split(operationSplitter())
            .handle(mqttOutbound())
            .get();
}
```

But i have the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MessageProducerSupport.java:136)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to use it in those `MessageProducerSupport` definitions, not like `channel("mainMessageChannel")`:

```
@Bean
MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
   ...
   adapter.setOutputChannelName("mainMessageChannel");
   ...
}

@Bean
MessageProducerSupport testInbound() {
   ...
   adapter.setOutputChannelName("mainMessageChannel");
   ...
}
```

or... Just don't `@Bean` annotation on them and Java DSL will take care about their declaration!